# Как передать значение json объекта с одного Activity в другой?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть rest api в котором есть категории и материалы категорий. Есть CategoryActivity в котором с помощью JsonObject и JsonArray я получаю список категорий в приложение.  Для того что бы получить материалы из каждой категории мне нужно сформировать запрос site.com/api/read_one_category.php?category_id=? где знак вопроса это id категории. В CategoryActivity я получаю id каждой категории.
Мне нужно сделать что бы при нажатие на текст названия категории бралось id той категории и передавалось на другое Activity в котором сформировался соответствующий url запроса.

Вот код активности с категориями

```
public class FaucetCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityFaucetCategoryBinding binding;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private static String CATEGORY_URL = "https://site.ru/api/category/read.php";

    List<CategoryModel> categoryList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityFaucetCategoryBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        //Ads init
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        //Ad Banner
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //Back to MainActivity
        binding.back.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intentback = new Intent(FaucetCategoryActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentback);
            finish();
        });

        categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.execute();
    }

    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String current = "";

            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try {
                    url = new URL(CATEGORY_URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    int data = isr.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isr.read();
                    }
                    return current;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return current;
        }

        

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records");

                for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                    categoryModel.setId(jsonObject1.getString("id"));
                    categoryModel.setName(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    categoryModel.setImg(jsonObject1.getString("img"));

                    categoryList.add(categoryModel);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            PutDataIntoRecyclerView(categoryList);
        }
    }

    private void PutDataIntoRecyclerView(List<CategoryModel> categoryList) {
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
```

Когда добавляю получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создал интерфейс с именем ICategorySelector и поместил

```
public interface ICategorySelector {
    public void passData(CategoryModel category);
}
```

Далее заменил строку `public class FaucetCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity` на `public class FaucetCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICategorySelector`

Потом создал метод в FaucetCategoryActivity

```
@Override
public void passData(CategoryModel category) {
    CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity.this);
}
```

Потом в CategoryAdapter создал конструктор

```
   public CategoryAdapter(FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity, List<CategoryModel> categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity1) {

    }
```

Потом в MyViewHolder добавил

```
ICategorySelector selector;

CategoryAdapter(...,ICategorySelector selector){
    this.selector=selector;
}
```

Что должно быть за месть ...?

Потом он не находит selector в holdere

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот полный код adapter

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<CategoryModel> mData;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }

    public CategoryAdapter(FaucetCategoryActivity mContext, List<CategoryModel> categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity) {
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.id.setText(mData.get(position).getId());
        holder.name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());


        //Using Glide library to display the image
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(mData.get(position).getImg())
                .into(holder.img);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selector.passData(arrayOfCategories[position]);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        CircleImageView img;

        ICategorySelector selector;
        void CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity, ICategorySelector selector){
            this.selector=selector;

        }

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
            img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);



        }

    }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы из адаптера получать значения элементов нужно сделать интерфейс и его объект передавать в адаптер. Вот например интерфейс:

```
public interface ICategorySelector {
    public void passData(CategoryModel category);
}
```

Дальше используем этот интерфейс в активности и переопределяем методы:

```
public class FaucetCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ICategorySelector
```

и передаем значение в конструктор адаптера списка:

```
CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity.this);
```

дальше в адаптере указываем в конструкторе что мы ожидаем интерфейс:

```
ICategorySelector selector;
RecycleAdapter(..., ICategorySelector selector){
   ....
   this.selector=selector;
}
```

при нажатии на элемент списка вызываем метод интерфейса:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           selector.passData(arrayOfCategories[position]);
        }
    });
```

и в активности в методе интерфейса обрабатываем его:

```
@Override
public void passData(CategoryModel model){
   //....
}
```

то есть например передать id категории в другую активность:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FaucetCategoryActivity.this, Result.class);
intent.putExtra("category_id",model.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Начиная с `дальше в адаптере указываем в конструкторе что мы ожидаем интерфейс:` запутался куда вставлять?

Comment: у вас есть адаптер для списка? у него наверное есть конструктор куда вы передаете список, правильно?

Comment: Посмотрите на изображение что я делаю не так?

Comment: три точки это то что у вас было до того как вы задали здесь этот вопрос))))) вам просто нужно добавить ещё в качестве параметра интерфейс :D

Comment: Подскажите что я делаю не так?

Comment: у вас был конструктор `FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity, List<CategoryModel> categoryList, FaucetCategoryActivity faucetCategoryActivity1` в адаптере, так? это и есть те три точки в моем ответе, дальше просто ставьте запятую и добавляйте ещё интерфейс

Comment: Потом он не находит selector в holdere

Comment: вам нужно разобраться с тем какие вы конструкторы используете, собрать все в один конструктор, и там присвоить полю класса-адаптера значение которое будет приходить из активности и все он будет находить, вы в холдере пытаетесь это сделать, а я предложил использовать onBindViewHolder

Comment: И всё равно я не доганяю, вроде на правильно пути, но всё равно на месте. Чокнусь скоро

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно? Вроде всё относительно просто